# Observable from Futures - onNext from multiple threads

Tags: scala, rx-java, observable, rx-scala

I want to generate an `Observable` in real time from the results of a list of `Futures`.

In the simplest case, suppose I have a list of futures I'm running with `Future.sequence`, and I'm simply monitoring their progress with an `Observable` that tells me each time one has completed. I'm basically doing it like this:

```
  def observeFuturesProgress(futs: List[Future[Int]]) : Observable[String] = {
    Observable[String](observer => {
      val loudFutures: List[Future[Int]] = futs.map(f => {
            f onComplete {
              case Success(a) => observer.onNext(s"just did $a more")
              case Failure(e) => observer.onError(e)
            }
            f
        })
      Future.sequence(loudFutures) onComplete {
          case Success(_) => observer.onCompleted()
          case Failure(e) => observer.onError(e)
      }
    })
  }
```

This works fine in my testing environment. But I've just read that `onNext` shouldn't be called from different threads, at least without being careful that there are no overlapping calls. What is the recommended way to fix this? It seems that many real-world uses of `Observables` would require `onNext` to be called from async code like this, but I can't find a similar example in the docs.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better answer, but you can ensure that `onNext` calls are run by the same thread if you use for example a single threaded execution context (`ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())`) to run those `onComplete`s callbacks.

Comment: Can you reference which article, regarding `onNext` are you referring to? This use case is perfectly fine, from my point of view.

Comment: @mavarazy: Much of the documentation I've found on this is pretty unclear but [this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/serialize.html) talks about using `serialize()` to avoid two overlapping `onNext()` calls, and [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject) warns you not to call `onNext()` from multiple threads - at least if you're using a Subject. And all of the Rx official examples I could find are single-threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)

> Observables must issue notifications to observers serially (not in
>   parallel). They may issue these notifications from different threads,
>   but there must be a formal happens-before relationship between the
>   notifications.

Take a look at [Serialize](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/serialize.html)

> It is possible for an Observable to invoke its observers’ methods
>   asynchronously, perhaps from different threads. This could make such
>   an Observable violate the Observable contract, in that it might try to
>   send an OnCompleted or OnError notification before one of its OnNext
>   notifications, or it might make an OnNext notification from two
>   different threads concurrently. **You can force such an Observable to be
>   well-behaved and synchronous by applying the Serialize operator to it.**

Comment: Thanks. When I'd quickly looked at the Serialize page before I'd been discouraged by the fact that the Rx-scala section just says TBD and doesn't give the actual syntax. I wasn't sure whether it had ever been implemented. However, the following syntax compiles: `Observable[String](observer => { ... }).serialize`, and it seems to run fine. I can't honestly tell yet whether `.serialize` does anything - for that I'll try building some tougher stress-tests. I'm also surprised it isn't the default implementation of `Observable`.